# Where does Google Chrome keep its bookmarks; how do I sync with other browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I just upgraded to Google Chrome on the Mac. It automatically keeps my bookmarks synchornized through my google account. But I can't figure out **where** those bookmarks are kept or how to access them.

I'd really like to sync those bookmarks with Safari on mac and with Firefox on mac, windows, and Linux. And even with IE on Windows. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [help page](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=165138):

> **Your synced bookmarks also show up in
>   Google Docs**. They appear in a new
>   folder called "Google Chrome." So if
>   you ever need to access your bookmarks
>   on a different browser or computer,
>   you can just visit Google Docs.

Personally, I use [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) to sync all my browsers/machines to each other. There are extensions for all the major browsers (including IE).

Comment: +1 for Xmarks too. Been using it since it was Foxmarks...

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to put all of my personal information at only one company...

Answer (score 0):

I like to advise to use [Delicious Extensions for Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/delicious-chrome-extension).